# If a Sequence of Polynomials Converge to Another Polynomial Then the Roots Also Converge.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Proposition 5.2.1 in Artin states that:

> > **THEOREM.** Let $p_k(t)\in \mathbf C[t]$ be a sequence of monic polynomials of degree $\leq n$, and let $p(t)\in \mathbf C[t]$ be another monic polynomial of degree $n$.
> >         Let $\alpha_{k,1},\ldots,\alpha_{k,n}$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be the roots of these polynomials.
> >         If 
> >         $$\lim_{k\to\infty}p_k=p$$
> >         then the roots $\alpha_{k,\nu}$ of $p_k(t)$ can be numbered in such a way that 
> >         $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\alpha_{k,\nu}=\alpha_{\nu},
> >  \quad
> >  \forall \nu=1,\ldots,n.
> >  $$

There is a simple proof given in Artin.
I approached the problem using the inverse function theorem and for that I required a more stringent hypothesis to prove the theorem.
Under this new stringent hypothesis, I was able to say something more(see the boxed part i the Lemma below) about the roots of the polynomials $p_k(t)$.

> > **LEMMA.** Let $p_k(t)\in\mathbf R[t]$ be a sequence of monic polynomials of degree no more than $n$, and let $p(t)\in\mathbf R[t]$ be another monic polynomial of degree $n$.
> >         Let $\alpha_{k,1},\ldots,\alpha_{k,n}$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ denote the roots of the polynomials $p_k(t)$ and $p(t)$ over the field $\mathbf C$.
> >         Assume that $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are real and pairwise distinct.
> >         Then if 
> >         $$\lim_{n\to\infty}p_k\to p$$
> >         There exists $K\in\mathbf N$ such that 
> >         $$
> >   \boxed{k\geq K
> >   \quad
> >   \Rightarrow
> >   \quad
> >   \alpha_{k,1},\ldots,\alpha_{k,n}\text{ are real and pairwise distinct.}}
> >  $$
> >         Further, $\alpha_{k,1},\ldots,\alpha_{k,n}$ can be numbered in such a way that 
> >         $$
> >  \lim_{k\to\infty}\alpha_{k,\nu}=\alpha_{\nu},
> >  \quad
> >  \forall \nu=1,\ldots,n.
> >  $$

***(The Problem)*** The proof of this is presented below. I am curious as to how to adjust for the case when the roots of $p(t)$ are not all distinct (This leads to a singular point of the function $f$ defined below not allowing to use the inverse function theorem) and also how to cover the complex case using this approach.

**PROOF.** For each $r\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, define $S_r:\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R$ as
    $$
  S_r(x_1\ldots,x_n)=(-1)^r\left[\sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\left(\prod_{j=1}^l x_{i_j}\right)\right]
 $$
    ($S_r$ is the $r$-th symmetric function on the letters $x_1,\ldots,x_n$).
    Now define a function $f:\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R^n$ as
    $$
  f(\mathbf x)=(S_1(\mathbf x),\ldots,S_n(\mathbf x)),
  \quad
  \forall \mathbf x\in \mathbf R^n
 $$
    where $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.
    It can be shown that:
    \begin{equation*}
 |\det(Df(x_1,\ldots,x_n))|=\left|\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i-x_j)\right|,
 \quad
 \forall (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbf R^n
 \tag{1}
 \end{equation*}
    So by hypothesis, $\det(Df(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n))\neq 0$.
    So by the Inverse Function Theorem, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ in $\mathbf R^n$ such that $f|_U:U\to f(U)$ is a smooth diffeomorphism.
    Write $V=f(U)$ and say $g:V\to U$ be the inverse of $f|_U$.
    Let 
    $$
 [t^r](p_k(t))=a_r^k,\quad
 \forall k\in\mathbf N, 0\leq r\leq n-1
 $$
    and
    $$
  [t^r](p(t))=a^r,
  \quad
  \forall 0\leq r\leq n-1
 $$
    where $[t^r]f(t)$ denotes the coefficient of the $r$-th power of $t$ in the expression of $f(t)$.
    For each $k\in\mathbf N$ write $\mathbf a^k=(a_{n-1}^k,\ldots,a_0^k)$ and also write $\mathbf a=(a_{n-1},\ldots,a_0)$.
    Note that $\lim_{k\to\infty}p_k=p$ says nothing but $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbf a^k=\mathbf a$.
    Thus there exists $K\in\mathbf N$ such that
    $$
  k\geq K
  \quad
  \Rightarrow
  \quad
  \mathbf a^k\in V
 $$
    We claim that for each $k\geq K$, $p_k(t)$ has $n$-distinct pairwise distinct real roots.
    To see this fix $k\geq K$ and let $g(\mathbf a^k)=(\beta_{k,1},\ldots,\beta_{k,n})=\boldsymbol \beta_k$.
    Then Since $\boldsymbol \beta_k\in U$, we have $\det Df(\boldsymbol\beta_k)\neq 0$.
    Thus by (1) $\beta_{k,1},\ldots,\beta_{k,n}$ are pairwise distinct.
    Also since $S_r(\boldsymbol \beta_{k})=a^k_{n-r}=[t^{n-r}](p_k(t))$,we see that $\beta_{k,1},\ldots,\beta_{k,n}$ are all the roots of $p_k(t)$.
    So our claim is proved.
    Now we will show that the roots $\alpha_{k,1},\ldots,\alpha_{k,n}$ of $p_k(t)$ can be numbered in such a way that the $\lim_{k\to\infty}\alpha_{k,\nu}=\alpha_{\nu}$.
    But this is clear since by continuity of $g$, we have
    $$
  \lim_{k\to\infty}\beta_{k,\nu}=\alpha_\nu,
  \quad
  \forall 1\leq\nu\leq n
 $$
    Noting that $\beta_{k,\nu}$'s are a permutation of $\alpha_{k,\nu}$'s, we are done.

Comment: What chapter is this in? It's from "Algebra" correct?

Comment: Yes. It is prop. 5.2.1 so it must be chapter 5. I do not have the book right now. It was from the second edition.