# If $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=2,$ show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Question: Suppose $f:(-\delta,\delta)\to (0,\infty)$ has the property that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=2.$$ Show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$.

My approach: Let $h:(-\delta,\delta)\to(-1,\infty)$ be such that $h(x)=f(x)-1, \forall x\in(-\delta,\delta).$ Note that if we can show that $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=0$, then we will be done. Now since we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=2\implies \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(f(x)-1)^2}{f(x)}=0\implies \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h^2(x)}{h(x)+1}=0.$$ Next I tried to come up with some bounds in order to use Sandwich theorem to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)=0,$ but the bounds didn't quite work out. The bounds were the following: $$\begin{cases}h(x)\ge \frac{h^2(x)}{h(x)+1},\text{when }h(x)\ge 0,\\h(x)<\frac{h^2(x)}{h(x)+1},\text{when }h(x)<0.\end{cases}$$

How to proceed after this?

Comment: :(−,)→(0,∞). I would have thought :ℝ→ℝ, no?

Comment: @mjw I don't think you need $f$ to be defined on the entire real line. It is enough for $f$ to be defined on some $\delta-$neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Okay, now it is clear.  $f$ maps an open interval to the positive $x-$axis.  For some reason, read it as an ordered pair.  Notation is a bit overloaded $\cdots.$  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Please see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445127/72031). There are many other threads dealing with same question which you can find via approach0. I am not closing this as a dupe because you want help with your specific approach.

Comment: Why not just use AM-GM inequality?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution.** Although not the most straightforward one, let me present a quick solution: First, we note that

$$ \lim_{x\to0} \left| f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)} \right|
= \lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{\left(f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)^2 - 4}
= 0, $$

Then by using $\max\{a,b\} = \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{|a-b|}{2}$ and $\min\{a,b\} = \frac{a+b}{2} - \frac{|a-b|}{2}$ which hold for any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, we get

$$ \lim_{x\to0} \max\biggl\{ f(x), \frac{1}{f(x)} \biggr\} = 1 = \lim_{x\to0} \min\biggl\{ f(x), \frac{1}{f(x)} \biggr\}. $$

Now the desired conclusion follows by the squeezing theorem.

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution.** We have

$$ \left| f(x) - 1 \right| = \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1} \left|f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)}\right| \leq \left|f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)}\right|. $$

Since we know that $\lim_{x\to0} \left| f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)} \right| = 0$, the desired claim follows by the squeezing theorem.

Comment: Very similar to what I was thinking: if $g(x) := f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$, then $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} (g(x) \pm \sqrt{(g(x))^2 - 4})$ so in particular $\frac{1}{2} (g(x) - \sqrt{(g(x))^2 - 4}) \le f(x) \le \frac{1}{2} (g(x) + \sqrt{(g(x))^2 - 4})$.

Comment: Hi Sangchul.  I hope that you are doing well and continuing to stay safe and healthy.  For your "2nd Solution,"  How do you justify the equality $|f-1|=\sqrt{f\left(f-\frac1f\right)^2}$?  Unless I am miscalculating in my head, which is always possible, I don't believe that can be correct.

Comment: @MarkViola, I am doing well, and hop you do so! It seems that I made some mistakes there, missing some factors. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Thank you my friend!  My family and I are doing well.  Here, $$f^2-1=f^2\left(f-\frac1f\right)^2$$

Comment: @MarkViola, I adopted your identity in a slightly different fashion (or so I believe). Hope this is now correct :)

Comment: @SangchulLee Now that works and you used $f>0$, which was a given piece of information.  (+1)

Comment: @MarkViola: The assumption $f > 0$ is not necessary. Actually Sangchul answered a more general question I asked a few years ago here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352152/if-a-nb-n-to-1-and-a-nb-n-to2-do-a-n-b-n-to1. The result there clarifies $f$ can be an arbitrary complex-valued function.

Answer (score 6):

If the result is false, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that no $\delta>0$ works. Thus there exists a sequence $x_n\to 0$ such that $|f(x_n)-1|\ge \epsilon$ for all $n.$ WLOG, $f(x_n)\ge1+\epsilon$ for all $n.$

Let $g(x) = x+1/x$ for $x\in [1,\infty).$ It's easy to see that $g$ is strictly increasing on this interval. Thus we have $(g\circ f)(x_n) \ge g(1+\epsilon) > 1$ for all $n.$ It follows that $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)+1/f(x))=1$ is false, contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

By definition of limit we have $\forall \varepsilon>0$

$$\left| f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} - 2 \right|=\left| \frac{(f(x)-1)^2}{f(x)}  \right| < \varepsilon$$

and since

$$\left| \frac{(x-1)^2}{x}  \right| < 1 \implies \left|\frac{x-1}x\right|<\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2<2$$

assuming wlog $\varepsilon <1$ we have

$$\left| \frac{(f(x)-1)^2}{f(x)}  \right| =\left|f(x)-1 \right|\left| \frac{f(x)-1}{f(x)}  \right|< 2\left|f(x)-1 \right|<\varepsilon \implies \left|f(x)-1 \right|<\frac{\varepsilon}2$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a somewhat amusing solution, this is a special case of [a question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352152/if-a-nb-n-to-1-and-a-nb-n-to2-do-a-n-b-n-to1) a few years ago. If $a_n,b_n$ are two sequences (real or complex), such that $a_n+b_n\to 2$, and $a_nb_n\to 1$, then $a_n$ and $b_n$ both converge to $1$. There are a few different proofs of that on the page I linked to.

In this case, we take $a_n = f(x_n)$ and $b_n = 1/f(x_n)$ for any sequence $x_n\to 0$. Then by assumption $a_n + b_n \to 2$ and $a_nb_n$ is identically equal to $1$, so the hypotheses are satisfied. Note that the hypothesis that $f$ be a strictly positive function is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Just as @ Sangchul Lee, we can get
$$\lim_{x\to0} \left| f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)} \right|
= \lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{\left(f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)^2 - 4}
= 0.$$
It is easy to see that
$$\lim_{x\to0} \left| f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)} \right|=0\iff
\lim_{x\to0} \left( f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)=0.$$
By
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left( f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)} \right)+\left( f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)\right],$$
we know
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1.$$

Comment: (+1) I am surprised that I missed this easy solution. Nice!

Comment: No best but only better！

Answer (score 2):

Setting $y = f(x) + \dfrac{1}{f(x)} \to 2$ we have
$$
f(x) = \frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2} \to \frac{2\pm\sqrt{2^2-4}}{2} = 1.
$$

The limit can be justified using the squeeze theorem, since $f(x) = \frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2},$ i.e. $f(x)$ equals either $\frac{y-\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2}$ or $\frac{y+\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2},$ implies $\frac{y-\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{y+\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative quick method:

We can easily deduce that, $$0<\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x)≤\limsup_{x\to 0}f(x)<+ \infty$$

Let, $\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x)=M, M>0$ and $\limsup_{x\to 0}f(x)=N, N>0$

Then, we have:

> $$\begin{align}2=\limsup_{x\to 0}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)≥\liminf_{x\to 0} f(x)+\limsup\dfrac {1}{ f(x)} \Longrightarrow \liminf_{x\to 0} f(x)+\dfrac {1}{\liminf_{x\to 0} f(x)} ≤2  \Longrightarrow M+\dfrac 1M ≤2 \Longrightarrow M+\dfrac 1M -2≤0 \Longrightarrow \dfrac{ \left(M-1\right)^2}{M}≤0\Longrightarrow \left(M-1\right )^2≤0 \Longrightarrow M=1\end{align}$$
>
> $$\begin{align}2=\limsup_{x\to 0}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)≥\limsup_{x\to 0} f(x)+\liminf\dfrac {1}{ f(x)} \Longrightarrow \limsup_{x\to 0} f(x)+\dfrac {1}{\limsup_{x\to 0} f(x)} ≤2 \Longrightarrow N+\dfrac 1N ≤2 \Longrightarrow N+\dfrac 1N -2≤0 \Longrightarrow \dfrac{ \left(N-1\right)^2}{N}≤0 \Longrightarrow \left(N-1\right )^2≤0  \Longrightarrow N=1\end{align}$$

Finally, we get $$\begin{align} \liminf _{x\to 0}f(x)=\limsup_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1.\end{align}$$

I used :

- $$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n + \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n \leq \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n + b_n).$$

Comment: First sentence: why is that obvious?

Comment: You have shown that if the limit of $f$ exists, it must be nonzero finite. But it is not obvious (to me) that the limit must exist

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read if you let $\lim \sup_{x \to 0}f(x)=M$ and $\lim \inf_{x \to 0}=m.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  is my solution correct?

Comment: yes it's correct.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  My edit count is terrible.  I finally could it..  Thanks for checking..

Comment: @zhw. I edited my answer.

Comment: @user658409 I fixed/corrected my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\Big(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\big)=2$ along with the assumption $f(x)>0$ implies that $f(x)$ is bounded in some subinterval $(-a,a)\setminus\{0\}$ with $0<a<\delta$, for there is $0<a<\delta$ such that
$$
\Big|f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)} -2\Big|<1
$$
which is equivalent to $|f(x)-1|^2<f(x)$ and so $\alpha=1+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}<f(x)<1+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\beta$.

This any sequence $\{x_n\}\subset(-a,a)$ that converges to $0$ has a subsequence $x_{n'}$ such that $f(x_{n'})$ converges to some number $p$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Hence

$$p+\frac{1}{p}=2$$
which means that $p=1$. This is independent of the sequence $x_n\rightarrow0$; consequently,

- $f(x)$ converges as $x\rightarrow0$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=1$

Comment: My edit was to change "ichi" to "which". We should not assume $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. But we must have $f>0$ on a nbhd of $0$, else $f(x)+1/f(x)$ could not converge to a positive value as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $t>0$,
let $\phi(t) = t+ {1 \over t}$ and note that $\phi(t) = y $ **iff** $t = {1 \over 2} (y \pm\sqrt{y^2-4})$.

Suppose $x_n \to 0$ and let $t_n = f(x_n)$. We are given that $y_n =\phi(t_n) \to 2$ (note that we must have $y_n \ge 2$).

We have $t_n \in \{ {1 \over 2} (y_n - \sqrt{y_n^2-4}), {1 \over 2} (y_n + \sqrt{y_n^2-4}) \}$ from which it follows that $t_n \to 1$.

Comment: I obviously missed your solution when I posted practically the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will start off with a fairly general lemma about limiting behavior of roots of a parameterized polynomial equation:

**Lemma:** Consider the polynomial equation $x^n + t_{n-1} x^{n-1} + t_{n-2} x^{n-2} + \cdots + t_0 = 0$.  Then as $t_{n-1}, \ldots, t_0 \to 0$, all $n$ complex roots of this equation also approach 0.  To be precise: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|t_i| < \delta$ for $i = 0, \ldots, n-1$ and $x^n + t_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + t_0 = 0$, it follows that $|x| < \epsilon$.

**Proof:** If $x$ is a root of the polynomial equation, then it follows that $|t_{n-i} x^{n-i}| \ge \frac{1}{n} |x|^n$ for some $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ -- since otherwise, we would have $|x^n + t_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + t_0| \ge |x|^n - |t_{n-1} x^{n-1}| - \cdots - |t_0| > 0$, giving a contradiction.  Therefore, for this value of $i$, we have $|x| \le |t_{n-i} n|^{1/i}$ ("even if $x=0$").  Since $|t_{n-i} n|^{1/i} \to 0$ for each $i$ as $t_0, \ldots, t_{n-1} \to 0$, the desired result follows. $\square$

---

Now, to apply this lemma to the original problem, let us set $g(x) := f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} - 2$.  Then $f(x) - 1$ satisfies the equation $(f(x) - 1)^2 - g(x) (f(x) - 1) - g(x) = 0$; and by assumption, we have $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 1$.  Therefore, by a typical "composition of limits" type argument combined with the lemma above, we can conclude that $f(x) - 1 \to 0$ as $x \to 1$.

Comment: Huh, it just occurred to me that I'd never really considered the possibility of defining the "limit of a relation" before, treating the relation as representing a multi-valued function.

Comment: I do have to admit, though, that this solution was mostly inspired by the thoughts of.. well, we can solve for $f$ in terms of $g$ using the quadratic equation.  But what about similar problems involving higher order polynomials which can't be solved by radicals anymore?  e.g. show that if $(f(t))^5 - t f(t) - t = 0$ then $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There must exist $d>0$ such that $$ 0<|x|<d\implies 0<f(x)\le 3$$ because $f(x)> 3 \implies f(x)+1/f(x)>3$... (and because $f(x)<0\implies f(x)+1/f(x)<0,$ while $f(x)+1/f(x)$ does not exist if $f(x)=0).$

For such $d$ we have $$0<|x|<d\implies \frac {(f(x)-1)^2}{3}\le \frac {(f(x)-1)^2}{f(x)}.$$ Hence $(f(x)-1)^2\to 0,$ so $f(x)-1\to 0.$